# Mixing Angular & Non Angular Into Page Object Pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, pageobjects

I have a question that is related to the the following link

[PageObjects + non-angular page - how to join them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950589/pageobjects-non-angular-page-how-to-join-them/38787245#38787245)

However, I do this using protractor-cucumber-framework rather than jasmine. The log in process is the following

1. Navigate to home page & enter credentials [angular]
2. Wait for iFrame pop up [non-angular]
3. Continue login process on iFrame [non-angular]
4. iFrame disappears and user is returned to home page [angular]

As the four steps listed are part of the logon process ideally I would like to store fields for the angular & non-angular elements in the one page object pattern

My steps are listed below:

```
this.Given(/^A User Navigates To The (.+)$/, {timeout: 60 * 1000}, function (AcaExternalLoginPage)
{

    //1. Navigate To Webpage
    return Page = new Page();

});

this.When(/^Employer Code (.+) Is Entered And User Logs On$/, {timeout: 20 * 1000}, function (EmployerCode)
{

    //1. Enter <EmployerCode> & Press Login In Button
    return Page.EmployerEnterCodeAndLogin(EmployerCode);

});

this.Then(/^The Browser Title Should Equal (.+) And The Popup Frame Should Display (.+)$/, {timeout: 20 * 1000}, function (BrowserTitle, PopupFrameGreeting)
{

    var World = this;

    //1. Expect Browser Title To Equal Passed In Value
    expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal(BrowserTitle);

    return this.RunNonAngular(function()
    {

        expect(browser.isElementPresent(Page.EmployerSssiFrame)).to.eventually.equal(true);

        Page.SwitchToEmployerSssiFrame;

        expect(Page.EmployerSssDynamicPromptLabel).to.eventually.equal(true);

        //2. Pop up Frame To Equal Passed In Value
        /expect(Page.TextEmployerSssDynamicPromptLabel).to.eventually.equal(PopupFrameGreeting);

    })

});
```

And My Page object Pattern is

```
'use strict';

var Page = function ()
{

    var baseUrl = 'http://172.16.87.185:54810/';

    browser.get(baseUrl + 'login');

};

Page.prototype = Object.create({},
{

    //1: Element Locators

    EmployerNameCodeTextBox:
    {

        get: function ()
        {

            return element(by.id('employee-code'));

        }

    },

    EmployerLoginButton:
    {

        get: function ()
        {

            return element(by.buttonText('Login'));

        }

    },

    EmployerSssiFrame:
    {

        get: function ()
        {

            return element(by.id('fbContent'));

        }

    },

    EmployerSssDynamicPromptLabel:
    {

        get: function ()
        {

            return element(by.id('lblRequestActionText'));

        }

    },

    //2. Actions|Events

    EmployerEnterCodeAndLogin:
    { 

        value: function (EmployerNameCode)
        {

            this.EmployerNameCodeTextBox.sendKeys(EmployerNameCode);

            this.EmployerLoginButton.click();

        }

    },

    SwitchToEmployerSssiFrame:
    {

        value: function ()
        {

            //Need to switch this way because of issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1846
            browser.switchTo().frame(this.EmployerSssiFrame.getWebElement());

        }

    },

    //3. Static Text Retrieval

    TextEmployerSssDynamicPromptLabel:
    {

        get: function ()
        {

            return this.EmployerSssDynamicPromptLabel.getText();

        }

    }

});

module.exports = Page;
```

Ideally I would like to keep the page objects on the one page as they are all part of the login process. When it gets to block

```
return this.RunNonAngular(function()
```

it timeouts as it is unable to find the iframe. Any suggestions on how to circumvent this? Maybe storing iFrame elements in another page (although this isn't ideal) & initializing later? Thanks in advance.